# What are the extra containers removed by "docker container prune" not listed by "docker ps -a"?

Tags: docker

```
~/tmp/Counter1 ⌚ 10:18:24
$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE          COMMAND                  CREATED        STATUS                    PORTS     NAMES
a46d397337e6   xx             "echo ls"                20 hours ago   Exited (0) 20 hours ago             cranky_snyder
28d7339e57aa   bf3a41a4ae8f   "/bin/sh -c 'echo $e…"   21 hours ago   Exited (0) 21 hours ago             unruffled_archimedes

~/tmp/Counter1 ⌚ 10:18:27
$ docker container prune
WARNING! This will remove all stopped containers.
Are you sure you want to continue? [y/N] y
Deleted Containers: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Total reclaimed space: 0B
```

If I repeat the same thing, I see the right number of docker container removed. But after some time of playing with more containers, I again see a similar mismatch in the number of containers.
If I understand correctly, `docker ps -a` should show me all containers. Wonder what the other SHAs are from?